# Google Maps not Showing in higher version in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating a Google Map with a custom latitude and longitude marker. The markers show properly on a Samsung S4 mobile, however they don't show on S8 or higher version. I grant all permission for that. I also put the click listener on the Custom Marker. These all work fine in S4 or low version, but not work in high version api mobile.

what is the issue? how to put run time permission for google map